# Balls in two sets of distinguishable boxes

Tags: probability, combinatorics, balls-in-bins

I'm dealing with a physics problem right now that essentially boils down to a ball and box problem. I know that the distribution of **N** indistinguishable balls into **k** distinguishable boxes is given by the multi-nomial distribution.

The problem that I'm working is a variant, where there are now two distinct sets of distinguishable boxes, and the number of balls distributed into each set can vary (i.e. $N$ = $N_{1}$ + $N_{2}$ where $N$ is fixed but $N_1$ and $N_2$ can vary.) I'm not sure what distribution describes this situation?

Comment: Maybe try the Hypergeometric Distribution?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I could be wrong, but I think this would be suitable for describing the distribution if the balls were labeled as either type 1 or type 2 instead of the boxes.

Comment: What number are you looking for?

Comment: if the boxes are already distinguishable, how does putting them into distinct sets make any difference?  if you want the number in a specific set (of the two), it's just binomial with $p = $ no. of boxes in the desired set $/ k$.